# Does Sonoma's predictive text work inside Electron?

Tags: text, electron, predictive, macos-sonoma

I haven't been able to get Sonoma's [predictive text](https://appleinsider.com/inside/macos-sonoma/tips/how-to-use-or-disable-inline-predictive-text-in-macos-sonoma) to work inside Electron. Is this supported?

Typing "Have a " will suggest "Have a nice day" in iMessage, but it won't do the same in any Electron-based apps, or Chrome.

Mac's text replacement works (omw --> On my way!), as does the emoji picker.